# flink scala streaming error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.util.PropertiesUtil.getBoolean(Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

```
 flink-1.2.0]# ./bin/flink run /streaming/mvn-flinkstreaming-scala/mvn-flinkstreaming-scala-1.0.jar
```

Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:6123
Using address localhost:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://localhost:8081
Starting execution of program

---

The program finished with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.util.PropertiesUtil.getBoolean(Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:101)
    at com.gavstech.streams.flink.StreamingJob$.main(StreamingJob.scala:21)
    at com.gavstech.streams.flink.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:339)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1073)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1120)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1117)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1116)
```

Pom.xml  snapshot

```
    <flink.version>1.10.0</flink.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
    <scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
```

Comment: Please show us which flink jars you have included as dependencies in pom.xml. Such errors usually indicate that either necessary dependencies have been left out, or that incompatible versions of flink are being used together.

Comment: Are you trying to run a Flink 1.10.0 job in a Flink 1.2.0 cluster? That's not going to work.

Comment: you are right David, I updated the flink version to 1.10.0 now iam able to submit the jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by running a Flink 1.10.0 client on a Flink 1.2.0 cluster. Upgrading the cluster to 1.10.0 solved the issue.

Comment: I have one more stack question for Cluster kindly look into it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60615984/flink-cluster-startup-error-error-could-not-get-jvm-parameters-properly

Comment: currently I am having challenge with job submission in flink cluster, kindly have your view, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722910/flink-job-error-java-util-concurrent-executionexception-org-apache-flink-runtim