# flink cluster startup error [ERROR] Could not get JVM parameters properly

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

```
$ bin/start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of standalonesession are already running on centos1.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host centos1.
[ERROR] Could not get JVM parameters properly.
[ERROR] Could not get JVM parameters properly.
```

I have got the $JAVA_HOME in all the master and slaves

```
]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/
```

Below are the config file settings.

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: 10.0.2.4
# The RPC port where the JobManager is reachable.
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 5
parallelism.default: 2
```

JPS in master:

```
]# jps
30944 QuorumPeerMain
9600 StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint
31640 ConsoleProducer
32889 Jps
31278 Kafka
```

in slave I am not able to see jps command output:

```
# jps
-bash: jps: command not found
```

Also under the task-manager i don't see any entries.
http://10.x.x.x:8081/#/task-manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure the conf/slaves file? See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/cluster_setup.html#configuring-flink.

The problem with jps doesn't look like a problem with Flink. Is there really a JDK on the slave?

Comment: yes JDK was the problem ]$ bin/start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of standalonesession are already running on centos1.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host centos1.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host centos2.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host centos3.

Comment: ,one more request, i beseech https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619913/flink-job-unfulfillableslotrequestexception-could-not-fulfill-slot-req-req-re