# Flink job .UnfulfillableSlotRequestException: Could not fulfill slot req. Req resource profile (ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}) is unfulfillable

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink job submission

```
$ ./bin/flink run -m 10.0.2.4:6123  /streaming/mvn-flinkstreaming-scala/mvn-flinkstreaming-scala-1.0.jar
Stream processing!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink@40ef3420

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: No pooled slot available and request to ResourceManager for new slot failed
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:607)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: No pooled slot available and request to ResourceManager for new slot failed
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.ResourceManagerException: Could not fulfill slot request 

    org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
```

but when i checked the logs of the job in UI getting a different error,

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: No pooled slot available and request to ResourceManager for new slot failed
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:607)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: No pooled slot available and request to ResourceManager for new slot failed
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.ResourceManagerException: Could not fulfill slot request ea
```

What should I check, my configuration parameter are as below,
A) is the -m ip_address:6123 right option or 8081 should be the port...
config..

```
# Note this accounts for all memory usage within the TaskManager process, including JVM metaspace and other overhead.

taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1568m

# To exclude JVM metaspace and overhead, please, use total Flink memory size instead of 'taskmanager.memory.process.size'.
# It is not recommended to set both 'taskmanager.memory.process.size' and Flink memory.
#
# taskmanager.memory.flink.size: 1280m

# The number of task slots that each TaskManager offers. Each slot runs one parallel pipeline.

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2

# The parallelism used for programs that did not specify and other parallelism.

parallelism.default: 2
```

Cluster starting,

```
$  bin/start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host centos1.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host centos2.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host centos3.
```

Able to process grep in master node,

```
]$ ps -ef | grep  flink
root      12300      1 10 07:22 pts/0    00:00:05 java -Xms16384m -Xmx16384m -Dlog.file=/storage/flink-1.10.0/log/
```

Unable to find a process of fink related to task managers, 
centos2 ~]$ psg flink

Is this a right state?

Comment: @David Anderson, please have a look at this challenge

Comment: How many slots do you have available according to your Web UI? Did you actually start the task managers?

Comment: should I start the task manager separatly, or does that gets started part of the cluster, or what is the way to start the task manager in flink

Comment: @ArvidHeise please find my comments on the cluster status in the main question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem in `Flink-1.10.0`. So please make sure you have enough memory according to the data load.

Error which i was getting:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

- jobmanager.heap.size: 1024m (Default)
- taskmanager.memory.flink.size: 1280m (Default)
- taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 256m (Default)

So I have increased `taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size` according to data load and it solved my issue.

For more details click [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/memory/mem_trouble.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem before, which is most likely an indicator for insufficient memory on your flink cluster. The different error messages also make sense, as they relate to each other.

Check your 
`jobmanager.heap.size`
and
`taskmanager.heap.size`
in the config, increase them to a rather oversized amount and you should not see this error anymore. From here you can finetune the actual memory settings

Comment: do you have any recommended size for it...Thanks for your comment

Comment: my current jobmanager.heap.size: 4096m, taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1024m and # taskmanager.memory.flink.size: 1280m is commented, Also my slave nodes are of 32G with 27 GB free memory

Comment: I haven't yet figured out an optimal ratio between all those configuration parameters. JobManager probably does not need as much in a simple scenario, however you should try adjusting `taskmanager.heap.size`(if it's not in your flink-conf yet, just add it) and put it to 4g or so, you got enough free space to try around.

Comment: now the slot error has disappeared,I have changed the jobmanager.heap.size: 8192m
taskmanager.heap.size: 4096m
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1024m  now i am getting the org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph. and some more Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.

Comment: Facing similar issue in docker, even thought i changed the heap size to a 16G

Comment: Is hard to identify the exact problem here but have you checked for disk space? I often ran into a problem of Flink generating lots of data (mostly logs) on a small disk, as I did not change the default directory in the configuration.