# Flink job error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink job submission

```
#  ./bin/flink run -m 10.0.2.4:6123 /storage/flink-1.10.0/examples/streaming/WordCount.jar --input /storage/flink-1.10.0/test.txt --output /storage/flink-1.10.0/test01.txt


------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.

$ ./bin/flink run -m 10.0.2.4:6123  /streaming/mvn-flinkstreaming-scala/mvn-flinkstreaming-scala-1.0.jar
Stream processing!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink@40ef3420

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:
    org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
```

how to troubleshoot this issue, I have tried with the example job and a sample streaming job, getting the same error for both the jar files.

Comment: @David Anderson please have a look at this issue.

Comment: @kopaka please have a look at this issue.

Comment: Need to revalidate my cluster configuration and job manager IP address on the task manger node as well.